# Using WP CLI to set options in WP Multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-cli, options

I have WP-CLI working fine using WP Multisite (or network). I can create blogs, add users, set permissions etc. But am not certain how to enable plugins for individual blogs via WP CLI.

For example, I can see for a specific blog that I have the following plugins enabled:

```
$ wp option get active_plugins --url=blogs.my.domain/test1
array (
  0 => 'active-directory-integration/ad-integration.php',
  1 => 'disable-comments/disable-comments.php',
  2 => 'http-authentication/http-authentication.php',
)
```

Which have been done by using the normal GUI and all is well.

However what I would like to do is set the options for each plugin - which I have done via WP CLI.  What I am not certain how to do is manipulate the associative array via `WP_CLI` in order to activate the plugins for each new site, at the moment understandably the `active_plugins` appear as follows even though the plugin's settings are in place:

```
$ wp option get active_plugins --url=blogs.my.domain/test2 array ()
```

So I would like to have the array set as the first example of a site where the plugins are enabled.

If someone can give me some clues as to how to manipulate and control associative arrays via WP CLI I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably manipulate the option with `wp option update` but you *shouldn't*.

It has plenty of dedicated commands for plugins, in your case it would probably be something like `wp plugin activate active-directory-integration,disable-comments,http-authentication --url=blogs.my.domain/test1`.

Comment: OK that is helpful, however there is an issue:

Answer (score 1):

Sorry need a long comment, so having to use an answer:

What you suggest works, but I have found an issue(bug?):

```
$ wp option get active_plugins --url=blogs.my.domain/undersea/submarinearray    (
)
```

Which is what I would expect, then activate the plugin:

```
$ wp plugin activate active-directory-integration --url=blogs.my.domain/undersea/submarine
Warning: Could not activate the 'active-directory-integration' plugin.
```

Which suggests that the plugin has not activated, but:

```
$ wp option get active_plugins --url=blogs.my.domain/undersea/submarinearray     (
  0 => 'active-directory-integration/ad-integration.php',
)
```

Tells me that it is active, which is not what I expected.

So deactivating the plugin:

```
$ wp plugin deactivate active-directory-integration --url=blogs.canterbury.ac.uk/undersea/submarine
Success: Plugin 'active-directory-integration' deactivated.
```

and to confirm:

```
$ wp option get active_plugins --url=blogs.my.domain/undersea/submarinearray (
)
```

Which is what I would expect.

So I get a correct message when a plugin is deactivated but not when one is, this is just a bit misleading.

I appreciate being able to do what I need to do, however the misleading message is not as helpful as I would like.

Many thanks

P.